# Static constructors in C++ on my own OS kernel

Tags: c++, operating-system, kernel, osdev

I am trying to write a kernel in c++ and I am a beginner in OS development. Now I am implementing `cout` to display on a monitor, but I am facing some problems. I know the question I am asking is foolish, but I am a newbie in c++ as well.

I have written an OStream class which calls the system function `write` to display on the screen. Its base class is my Video class. This class is included into namespace std. So the main problem is that when I create a object of OStream, it is not calling it's constructor and hence not calling the constructor of its base class, so that videomemory is not initialising and therefore nothing will be displayed on screen.

Here is my code:

```
/*OStream.h*/
namespace std{
class OStream:public Video{
    public:
    OStream();
    OStream& operator<<(int);
    OStream& operator<<(String);
    OStream& operator<<(char *cp);
    OStream& operator<<(char c);
    OStream& operator<<(unsigned char *cq);
    OStream& operator<<(unsigned char c1);
};
extern OStream cout;
}

/*OStream.cpp*/
namespace std{
    OStream cout;
    OStream::OStream(){}
    OStream& OStream::operator<<(char *cp){
        write(cp);
    }
    .
    . 
    .
    .
}
```

In the above code I am creating an object of `OStream` class in the OStream.cpp file itself.
But if I create an object in my main module then it calls its constructor successfully, but then `cout` is not working.

That means if I create an object explicitly it works perfectly, but how can I create an object implicitly.

And same thing is happening with my Interrupt.cpp module.

So please help me to solve this type of problem.
Please help me.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You say you are a newbie in both kernel development and C++. Both are very complex. I recommend you focus on one at at time. First learn C++, and then tackle the kernel.

Comment: When writing my own kernel I also thought about using C++, but it's really not worth the additional hassles. You can't use any standard library (either C or C++) at the beginning anyhow until you've got interrupts working, paging support, a kernel heap, etc.. So that will have to work with the basic functionality of the language (which is basically the same for both c and c++). Later on you can easily port both libraries to your kernel, but that's really not something you should worry about right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your implementation of `cout` is non-conforming. If you're going to be writing a C++ standard library, you must write it to be conforming to said standard (not to what you *think* the standard is).

Second, you need to implement static constructor support. You haven't specified your compiler, so all I can say is figure out where your compiler puts its static constructor initialization code, and make sure to invoke it on program startup.

You may have more luck adapting existing C++ libraries (GCC's libstdc++ or clang's libc++) to your new OS than writing one from scratch. Writing a C++ stdlib is NOT something for a beginner; you'll be neck-deep in template metaprogramming in no time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Sorry, I forgot to mention the compiler i am using.I am using GCC compiler to build kernel.

Comment: How can i use GCC's standard lib.While running OS there is no any runtime environment for OS.So that I should have to implement it or not?

Comment: @Dnyanesh, okay, so go look at the assembly output from GCC when it compiles a file with a static constructor now. You'll need to figure out how to invoke the static construction code it emits (take a look at glibc too, the actual invocation happens there on Linux)

Comment: And if you're writing your OS, you can make whatever runtime environment you want. You don't specify if this is for your OS's userspace or kernelspace; if this is for the kernel, I would recommend you just go with C, or alternately, go with a very limited subset of C++ (no static constructors, no exceptions, limited allocation etc etc)

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible to create an object without calling it's constructor. But with global variables like `cout` sometimes the time that the constructor gets called is a problem. If you have two global variables in different .cpp files then you cannot predict which global variable will get constructed first. Maybe that is the problem you are seeing? If so then the easy answer is to put all your global variables into one .cpp file (call it globals.cpp if you like). Then the global variables will get constructed in the order that you declare them within that .cpp file (and destructed in the reverse order).

Comment: If you're writing your own OS, anything is possible, including global objects without their constructor being called. This is a question about implementing C++ itself, not using it.

Comment: Ya, This happens only if i create an object in OStream.cpp file itself and i am declaring it as an `extern` in OStream.h to use it another module.And i am creating only one object of that class.